# Moving jBpm Tokens from one node to another manually in a processInstance, what issues to consider?

Tags: jbpm

For a project I need to move Tokens between nodes that have no transitions between them.

I can set the Node on Tokens and the signal them. This works fine on the root token.

But what else do I have to consider? What will happen when I want to move a token when it's child tokens are still between a fork and a join, or moving a token to a node on a single branch between a fork and a join?

From some experiences I found out that:

- You need to finish TaskInstances when you remove their token from their node.

But I am still looking for a generic way to move tokens in a flow without breaking the flow execution.

I am sure it's not such a uncommon requirement, so how did you solved this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> But I am still looking for a generic
>   way to move tokens in a flow without
>   breaking the flow execution.

Unfortunately this won't be possible. You can move them but have to take the internal working of jBPM into account. Updating parent tokens e.g. in fork/join constructions etc..

> I am sure it's not such a uncommon
>   requirement

It is and it is not.

> , so how did you solved
>   this?

Staying with the bare minimals and not move tokens in complex constructs.